# Wireless Broadcom 4313 not working on Ubuntu 12.04

Tags: 12.04, wireless, broadcom

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to Install Broadcom Wireless card (BCM43XX)](https://askubuntu.com/questions/55868/how-to-install-broadcom-wireless-card-bcm43xx)

It seems a lot of people are having this problem, but none of the posted solutions have worked for me so far. My driver is installed and activated, I have tried removing and re-adding the network, and various other fixes. No networks were picked up on my first boot, the next day wireless worked fine, and since then it does not detect networks, and when I manually try to connect, it repeatedly asks for the password and does not connect. Here's my info:

```
03:00.0 Network controller: Broadcom Corporation BCM4313 802.11b/g/n Wireless LAN Controller (rev 01)
    Subsystem: Dell Inspiron M5010 / XPS 8300
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 17
    Memory at f0500000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=16K]
    Capabilities: [40] Power Management version 3
    Capabilities: [58] Vendor Specific Information: Len=78 
    Capabilities: [48] MSI: Enable- Count=1/1 Maskable- 64bit+
    Capabilities: [d0] Express Endpoint, MSI 00
    Capabilities: [100] Advanced Error Reporting
    Capabilities: [13c] Virtual Channel
    Capabilities: [160] Device Serial Number 00-00-a1-ff-ff-f3-70-f1
    Capabilities: [16c] Power Budgeting 
    Kernel driver in use: wl
    Kernel modules: wl, bcma, brcmsmac


root@michelle-laptop:/home/michelle# ifconfig
eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 70:f1:a1:f3:ba:ab  
          inet6 addr: fe80::72f1:a1ff:fef3:baab/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:29
          TX packets:0 errors:30 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000
          RX bytes:0 (0.0 B)  TX bytes:0 (0.0 B)
          Interrupt:17

eth1      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr f0:4d:a2:53:83:7a  
          UP BROADCAST MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000
          RX bytes:0 (0.0 B)  TX bytes:0 (0.0 B)
          Interrupt:43

lo        Link encap:Local Loopback  
          inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
          inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
          UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:16436  Metric:1
          RX packets:104 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:104 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0
          RX bytes:8000 (8.0 KB)  TX bytes:8000 (8.0 KB)


root@michelle-laptop:/home/michelle# lsmod
Module                  Size  Used by
dm_crypt               22528  0
snd_hda_codec_hdmi     31775  1
snd_hda_codec_realtek   174313  1
snd_hda_intel          32765  5
snd_hda_codec         109562  3 snd_hda_codec_hdmi,snd_hda_codec_realtek,snd_hda_intel
snd_hwdep              13276  1 snd_hda_codec
snd_pcm                80845  4 snd_hda_codec_hdmi,snd_hda_intel,snd_hda_codec
snd_seq_midi           13132  0
snd_rawmidi            25424  1 snd_seq_midi
snd_seq_midi_event     14475  1 snd_seq_midi
snd_seq                51567  2 snd_seq_midi,snd_seq_midi_event
parport_pc             32114  0
ppdev                  12849  0
binfmt_misc            17292  1
lib80211_crypt_tkip    17275  0
bnep                   17830  2
rfcomm                 38139  0
snd_timer              28931  2 snd_pcm,snd_seq
snd_seq_device         14172  3 snd_seq_midi,snd_rawmidi,snd_seq
joydev                 17393  0
wl                   2646601  0
snd                    62064  19 snd_hda_codec_hdmi,snd_hda_codec_realtek,snd_hda_intel,snd_hda_codec,snd_hwdep,snd_pcm,snd_rawmidi,snd_seq,snd_timer,snd_seq_device
soundcore              14635  1 snd
btusb                  17912  0
bluetooth             158438  11 bnep,rfcomm,btusb
uvcvideo               67203  0
videodev               86588  1 uvcvideo
snd_page_alloc         14108  2 snd_hda_intel,snd_pcm
lib80211               14040  2 lib80211_crypt_tkip,wl
intel_ips              17822  0
psmouse                72919  0
serio_raw              13027  0
mei                    36570  0
dell_laptop            17767  0
dell_wmi               12601  0
dcdbas                 14098  1 dell_laptop
sparse_keymap          13658  1 dell_wmi
mac_hid                13077  0
lp                     17455  0
parport                40930  3 parport_pc,ppdev,lp
usbhid                 41906  0
hid                    77367  1 usbhid
wmi                    18744  1 dell_wmi
i915                  414817  3
atl1c                  36718  0
drm_kms_helper         45466  1 i915
drm                   197692  4 i915,drm_kms_helper
i2c_algo_bit           13199  1 i915
video                  19068  1 i915
root@michelle-laptop:/home/michelle# iwlist scan
lo        Interface doesn't support scanning.

eth1      Interface doesn't support scanning.

eth0      No scan results

root@michelle-laptop:/home/michelle# rfkill list
0: dell-wifi: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
1: dell-bluetooth: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: yes
    Hard blocked: no
3: brcmwl-0: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
```

Obviously I don't know what I'm doing. I'd appreciate any help! Thanks!

---

Further information as requested:

Update: At the moment I am connected to wireless but the driver is not activated. Wireless is still not working reliably.

Here's the info you requested:

```
03:00.0 0280: 14e4:4727 (rev 01)  
Subsystem: 1028:0010  
Control: I/O- Mem+ BusMaster+ SpecCycle- MemWINV- VGASnoop- ParErr- Stepping- SERR+ FastB2B- DisINTx-  
Status: Cap+ 66MHz- UDF- FastB2B- ParErr- DEVSEL=fast >TAbort- <TAbort- <MAbort- >SERR- <PERR- INTx-  
Latency: 0, Cache Line Size: 64 bytes  
Interrupt: pin A routed to IRQ 17  
Region 0: Memory at f0500000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=16K]  
Capabilities: [40] Power Management version 3  
    Flags: PMEClk- DSI- D1+ D2+ AuxCurrent=0mA PME(D0+,D1-,D2-,D3hot+,D3cold+)  
    Status: D0 NoSoftRst+ PME-Enable- DSel=0 DScale=2 PME-  
Capabilities: [58] Vendor Specific Information: Len=78 <?>  
Capabilities: [48] MSI: Enable- Count=1/1 Maskable- 64bit+  
    Address: 0000000000000000  Data: 0000  
Capabilities: [d0] Express (v1) Endpoint, MSI 00  
    DevCap: MaxPayload 128 bytes, PhantFunc 0, Latency L0s <4us, L1 unlimited  
        ExtTag+ AttnBtn- AttnInd- PwrInd- RBE+ FLReset-  
    DevCtl: Report errors: Correctable- Non-Fatal- Fatal- Unsupported-  
        RlxdOrd- ExtTag- PhantFunc- AuxPwr- NoSnoop-  
        MaxPayload 128 bytes, MaxReadReq 128 bytes  
    DevSta: CorrErr+ UncorrErr- FatalErr- UnsuppReq+ AuxPwr+ TransPend-
    LnkCap: Port #0, Speed 2.5GT/s, Width x1, ASPM L0s L1, Latency L0 <4us, L1 <64us  
        ClockPM+ Surprise- LLActRep+ BwNot-  
    LnkCtl: ASPM L0s L1 Enabled; RCB 64 bytes Disabled- Retrain- CommClk+  
        ExtSynch- ClockPM+ AutWidDis- BWInt- AutBWInt-  
    LnkSta: Speed 2.5GT/s, Width x1, TrErr- Train- SlotClk+ DLActive+ BWMgmt- ABWMgmt-  
Capabilities: [100 v1] Advanced Error Reporting  
    UESta:  DLP- SDES- TLP- FCP- CmpltTO+ CmpltAbrt- UnxCmplt- RxOF- MalfTLP- ECRC- UnsupReq- ACSViol-  
    UEMsk:  DLP- SDES- TLP- FCP- CmpltTO- CmpltAbrt- UnxCmplt- RxOF- MalfTLP- ECRC- UnsupReq- ACSViol-  
    UESvrt: DLP+ SDES- TLP- FCP+ CmpltTO- CmpltAbrt- UnxCmplt- RxOF+ MalfTLP+ ECRC- UnsupReq- ACSViol-  
    CESta:  RxErr+ BadTLP+ BadDLLP+ Rollover- Timeout+ NonFatalErr+  
    CEMsk:  RxErr- BadTLP- BadDLLP- Rollover- Timeout- NonFatalErr+  
    AERCap: First Error Pointer: 14, GenCap+ CGenEn- ChkCap+ ChkEn-  
Capabilities: [13c v1] Virtual Channel  
    Caps:   LPEVC=0 RefClk=100ns PATEntryBits=1  
    Arb:    Fixed- WRR32- WRR64- WRR128-  
    Ctrl:   ArbSelect=Fixed  
    Status: InProgress-  
    VC0:    Caps:   PATOffset=00 MaxTimeSlots=1 RejSnoopTrans-  
        Arb:    Fixed- WRR32- WRR64- WRR128- TWRR128- WRR256-  
        Ctrl:   Enable+ ID=0 ArbSelect=Fixed TC/VC=ff  
        Status: NegoPending- InProgress-  
Capabilities: [160 v1] Device Serial Number 00-00-a1-ff-ff-f3-70-f1  
Capabilities: [16c v1] Power Budgeting <?>  
Kernel driver in use: wl  
Kernel modules: wl, bcma, brcmsmac
```

Extra info, including syslog from when wireless was NOT working:
http://pastebin.ubuntu.com/1203671/

Based on advice from another thread, I blacklisted `mac80211`, `cfg80211`, `wl`, `lib80211_crypt_tkip`, and `lib80211`. I then added `modprobe brcm80211` to `rc.local`. Now when I boot up, nothing happens until I look at additional drivers. The STA driver is not enabled, and when I hit "activate," it comes up with an error message, but then immediately connects to the Internet without activating the driver. So I guess I just need to figure out how to make it do that automatically without having to go through trying to activate the driver. Here's what `syslog` looks like now: http://pastebin.ubuntu.com/1203702/

Comment: Just curious, when you are having trouble with not accepting a connection does it help to do a cold boot (shutdown the computer to a power off state rather than doing a restart)? Can you see anything that looks like an error message in /var/log/syslog? Can you include the lines for the wireless device from `lspci -vvn` ?

Comment: It's very strange. Different things happen every time I boot up my computer. Sometimes everything works automatically, sometimes the driver is enabled but wireless doesn't work, sometimes the driver is disabled but I can activate it (though wireless then still does not work), and sometimes I get an error message trying to activate the driver. I'll post the information you requested next time I'm at my computer (at the library now).

Comment: Ok, I added an update below. Sorry about the formatting!

Comment: /var/log/syslog contains log information from the system, so you ca display it with by using the Folder at the top left of your screen and navigating from "File System" to /var to /var/log and then to syslog. From there you should be able to copy and paste it.

Comment: There's a ton. I posted the end of it. Although maybe this isn't helpful since it was working at that time...

Comment: Would you mind putting it into pastebin.ubuntu.com and adding the result's URL to your question? Once it and the other new information is in the question it would probably be best if you could delete the answer with that information in it.

Comment: The contents of /var/log/syslog look like a good connection was made.